# Can't set default page on Azure site

Tags: azure, iis, azure-virtual-machine

I cannot view my custom index.html page. Here is what I've done so far:

- Created a new Windows OS 2012 VM
- Installed IIS and enable the default site.
- Under the default site I created an index.html with custom content.
- On the server, when I navigate to http://localhost it works. I can view my index.html page.
- When I try to access the page outside on my desktop, I get the standard iisstart.htm page.
- On my VM I have port 80 open inbound and outbound.
- On IIS I've set index.html as the default page for the website.
- I've restarted the VM, app pool and website as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can follow this steps to set default web page in IIS:

1.Add `index.html` in `wwwroot`:

[image]

2.Add port 80 to windows firewall inbound rules:

[image]

3.Add port 80 to Azure NSG inbound rules:

[image]
4.Browse it:

[image]

Hope this helps.